# Find locus of point

Tags: inequality, logarithms, solution-verification

If a complex number z satisfies $\log _{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{|z|^{2}+2|z|+6}{2|z|^{2}-2|z|+1}\right)<0$, then locus of point represented by z is

---

Since $\log _{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{|z|^{2}+2|z|+6}{2|z|^{2}-2|z|+1}\right)<0$

$\therefore \frac{|z|^{2}+2|z|+6}{2|z|^{2}-2|z|+1}<1$
$\Rightarrow|z|^{2}-4|z|-5>0$
$\Rightarrow(|z|-5)(|z|+1)>0 \Rightarrow|z|>5 \text{ and } |z|<-1$

*But the ans is given in the question is $|z|<5$*

Am i wrong???

Comment: For which z is $|z|<-1$?

Comment: @MartinR i am not getting u

Comment: Btw, your first conclusion is wrong because $1/2 < 1$.

Comment: in which part am I wrong ,kindly explain with proper logic!. I have simply followed all inequality rules as per my concern

Comment: $\log _{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{|z|^{2}+2|z|+6}{2|z|^{2}-2|z|+1}\right)<0$ implies $\frac{|z|^{2}+2|z|+6}{2|z|^{2}-2|z|+1}>1$. The inequality sign is reversed, because $\ln (1/2)$ is negative.

Comment: @MartinR thanks indeed. I am too dumb to notice that. pardon